# My JavaScript code won't run?

Tags: javascript, area

This code about area of a circle calculation can't run, I don't know what is wrong?

```
    <script> 

    var r=20; 
    var Pi=3.14; 
    var P=(Math.pow(r,2)*Pi); 
    document.write("r=20cm<br>" "'π'=3.14<br>" "P=r<sup>2</sup>'π'<br>" "P=" + (P) + "cm<sup>2</sup>"); 

    </script>
```

The code should in the end return this:
        r=20
        Pi=3.14
        P=r^2π
        P=result (here it should be 1256) cm^2.

Comment: define "won't run". Does it throw an exception?

Comment: Does the browser generate any errors?

Comment: Would the upvoter please explain? Is it because the score was negative?

Comment: As a complete aside to the question, `Math.PI` is a number that exists and represents a lot more than 2 decimal places

Comment: Also, avoid `document.write` and `<br/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your browser console, and you would see that it would display a message "Unexpected string".

```
document.write("r=20cm<br>" "'π'=3.14<br>" "P=r<sup>2</sup>'π'<br>" "P=" + (P) + "cm<sup>2</sup>");
```

Was the problem. You can only supply one string to be written. You would have to make those multiple strings a single one by adding `+` in between.

```
document.write("r=20cm<br>" + "'π'=3.14<br>" + "P=r<sup>2</sup>'π'<br>" + "P=" + (P) + "cm<sup>2</sup>");
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the + operators!

```
document.write("r=20cm<br>" + "'π'=3.14<br>" + "P=r<sup>2</sup>'π'<br>"+ "P=" + (P) + "cm<sup>2</sup>");
```

On a practical note, why would you want to concatenate strings like that? Why can't you just :

```
document.write("r=20cm<br>'π'=3.14<br>P=r<sup>2</sup>'π'<br>P=" + (P) + "cm<sup>2</sup>");
```